# How do I punctuate a hyperbole?

Tags: punctuation

I’m so hungry I could eat a horse. 
I’m so hungry, I could eat a horse. 
I’m so hungry; I could eat a horse.

It seems I have two independent clauses and need a semicolon.  It also seems like the second clause is dependent on the first clause, but I think complex sentences must have a subordinate conjunction.  I need to teach hyperbole on Monday and want to do it right. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t see what this has to do with hyperbole, other than that the example chosen happens to be an example of it. “I’m so hungry my stomach is rumbling” is not hyperbole; “this book weighs a ton” is. If you add in a semicolon, you turn it into two possibly unrelated clauses; if you don’t, you have a sentence consisting of a main clause and a dependent clause. Where do you get the idea that complex sentences must have a subordinator? Complementisers are nearly always deletable in English, and the dependent clause here is a complement clause.

Comment: Even if you *do* consider it to be two independent clauses, comma splices in short phrases like this [can be](http://grammartips.homestead.com/spliceok.html) acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm so hungry that I can eat a horse."  [talkenglish.com](https://www.talkenglish.com/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=806) and [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+could+eat+a+horse)

No punctuation required